# Make visible false an TextObject in crystal report

Tags: vb.net

With Visual studio 2013 And Button1 .. When i tried to make an TextObject named ( Text150 ) at visible = False .. I had an error under this line ( TextObject1.visible = False ).How to make an TextObject Or Box in Crystal report at visible = false
This is my code :

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim Report1 As New Crystal1

   If TextBox1.Text = VbNullString Then
   Dim TextObject1 As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject = Report1.Section2.ReportObjects("Text150")
   TextObject1.visible = False
   End If

   Dim Frm As New Form2
    Me.Dispose()
    Frm.Show()
    Frm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
    Frm.CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(100%)
    End Sub
```

Comment: It should be done in the report itself. Right click TextObject1, click Format Object. Under the Common tab, check Suppress. If you want to set it by condition, you can pass a parameter to the report. Then based on the parameters value, set the TextObject1's Suppress value by clicking the Formula editor button at the right of the Suppress checkbox.

Comment: Thank you .. In my Form1 I have TextBox1 . when I click Button1 to print I want if TextBox1 is empty then TextObject1 in Crystal1 named ( Text150)  will be invisible.I changed my code above.

Comment: You set the Suppress value from inside the Crystal Reports Designer.  It is also there that you add your Report Parameters.

Comment: How will be the formula of condition that I will write it .. please

Comment: Crystal Synatx `if {?paramVisible} then false else true  For Basic Syntax if {?paramVisible} then formula = false else formula = true end if1

Comment: Please, there is another simpler formula like this for example (If TextBox1.Text) = Nothing Then TextObjext150.Visible = False) ??

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible

Comment: Thank you very much .. I tried to put in TextObject in crystal report like this but not best result ( if(TextBox1.Text = "" then  Text object.visible = false else true)